# How to set the limit the count of events/tags in GTM to one?

Tags: google-tag-manager

Often times, events/conversions are only useful when counted once. Multiple firing of the same tag is not always idea.

Platforms like Google Ads have options like this but when using GTM for FB ads, it's not an option, at least from what I can see.

Does anyone know how to use GTM to maximize the occurrences of a tag fire?

Comment: One way to do it would be to drop a session cookie via GTM at the beginning of their session. Then, when they complete the event/conversion, increment it. For the FB tag, have it only fire if the cookie value is <1.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this setting in Tag.

Advanced setting -> Tag Firing Options

Once per page.
It will make sure this tag only fire once.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I don't think any of those 3 options give the expected output we're looking for. I think it would be "once per session" or something. I just checked the setting and the default it's set to presently is "once per event".